# Ответ бота на его пинг в дискорде

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хотел бы сделать так чтобы после того как я буду **@упоминать бота**, он будет отправлять сообщения в ответ, не подскажете как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать что-то похожее на генератор рандомных сообщений при упоминании бота, или что-то в этом роде. Смотрите, как это можно сделать:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    randommessage=['Зачем ты это сделал?', 'Привет, привет!', 'Вау, меня кто-то пинганул? Круто.']
    botuserid = f'<@!{bot.user.id}>'
    if botuserid  in message.content:
        await message.channel.send(f"{random.choice(randommessage)}")
```

А можно без рандомного сообщения при пинге. Просто убираете:

```
randommessage=['текст1', 'текст2']`
```

и в:

```
await message.channel.send('пишите свой текст!')
```

Comment: Ещё раз большое спасибо вам! :3

Comment: Да всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Можно через `on_message`

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "<@!id>":
        ...
```